# Ruby accessing instance variable of other object

Tags: ruby

I've been messing around with Ruby (Ruby 1.9.3, IRB 0.9.6(09/06/30)) and I'm trying to develop a complex number class. I have the `initialize` and `to_s` methods working fine. I'm now trying to overload the four arithmetic operators.

What I had is the following:

```
def +(other)
    return ComplexNumber.new(@real + other.@real, @imag + other.@imag)
end
```

but for some reason it didn't like `other.@real`; it says

> syntax error: unexpected tIVAR

and points to the comma after `other.@real`.

So then I changed it to:

```
def get_values
    return [@real, @imag]
end

def +(other)
    other_values = other.get_values
    return ComplexNumber.new(@real + other_values[0], @imag + other_values[1])
end
```

Although this works, I have a feeling that it's not the correct way to do it. I don't really want to expose the `get_values` method; isn't there some way I can access a variable of another instance of the same class?

Comment: Ruby has a Complex class out of the box: `puts '0.3-0.5i'.to_c.class  #=>Complex`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instance variables are accessed without the `@` when referring to another instance:

```
other.real
```

(Assuming you're either using `attr_accessor` to define them, or are providing your own accessors. Even within the same instance you  may prefer to use the accessors in case there's logic beyond simply returning the instance variable.)

Comment: When I used `other.real`, it assumed `real` was a method and threw an error. What's `attr_accessor`?

Comment: @WChargin http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/attr_accessor I don't know why you'd create a complex class without providing accessors for the different parts; almost anything with complex numbers would need them.

Answer (score 3):

The best way (in my opinion) would be to provide a read only access to the variables `real` and `imag` using `attr_reader`. Like:

```
class ComplexNumber
  attr_reader :imag, :real
  ...
  def +(other)
    return ComplexNumber.new(@real + other.real, @imag + other.imag)
  end
end
```

Note that attr_reader defines the methods on your behalf `.real()` and `.imag()` [`attr_accessor` additionally defines `.real=()` and `.image=()`]

Comment: So the four methods are private, I assume?

Comment: @WChargin Why do you assume that?

Comment: Because there are set methods, which seem intrusive. Is it just the set methods that are private and the get methods are public?

Comment: @WChargin No; they're all public. You can look up the docs for those methods (`attr_accessor`, `attr_reader`, etc.) too.